# Mongodb aggregation timeout

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a large collection about 200 mil documents. Documents are small but if I try to aggregate some data it fall down on timeout error. I am not sure if it is caused by indexes or by documents count.

The pipeline looks like:

```
{
    $match: {
        global_campaign_id: {$in: [3151 ,3207 ,3208 ,3209 ,3210 , ... (30 ids)]}
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            global_campaign_id: "$global_campaign_id", 
            device_id: "$device_id", 
            partner_id: "$partner_id"
        },
        date_last: {
            $max: "$date_created"
        },
        partner_id: {$first: "$partner_id"},
        campaign_id: {$first: "$global_campaign_id"},
        device_id: {$first: "$device_id"}
    }
}
```

Then I have this idexes on the collection:

```
_id: 1
date_created: 1,
global_campaign_id: 1,
global_campaign_id: 1, date_created: 1,
global_campaign_id: 1, device_id: 1, partner_id: 1, date_created: 1
```

What could be the problem? I need last document for every group. Could sort stage before group help?

---

Here is result of explain command

```
{
        "stages" : [
                {
                        "$cursor" : {
                                "queryPlanner" : {
                                        "plannerVersion" : 1,
                                        "namespace" : "lurity.impressions",
                                        "indexFilterSet" : false,
                                        "parsedQuery" : {
                                                "global_campaign_id" : {
                                                        "$in" : [
                                                                3151,
                                                                3207,
                                                                3208,
                                                                3209,
                                                                3210
                                                        ]
                                                }
                                        },
                                        "queryHash" : "901B446C",
                                        "planCacheKey" : "06CC82FF",
                                        "winningPlan" : {
                                                "stage" : "PROJECTION_COVERED",
                                                "transformBy" : {
                                                        "date_created" : 1,
                                                        "device_id" : 1,
                                                        "global_campaign_id" : 1,
                                                        "partner_id" : 1,
                                                        "_id" : 0
                                                },
                                                "inputStage" : {
                                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                                "global_campaign_id" : 1,
                                                                "device_id" : 1,
                                                                "partner_id" : 1,
                                                                "date_created" : 1
                                                        },
                                                        "indexName" : "global_campaign_id_1_device_id_1_partner_id_1_date_created_1",
                                                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                                                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                                "global_campaign_id" : [ ],
                                                                "device_id" : [ ],
                                                                "partner_id" : [ ],
                                                                "date_created" : [ ]
                                                        },
                                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                                "global_campaign_id" : [
                                                                        "[3151.0, 3151.0]",
                                                                        "[3207.0, 3207.0]",
                                                                        "[3208.0, 3208.0]",
                                                                        "[3209.0, 3209.0]",
                                                                        "[3210.0, 3210.0]"
                                                                ],
                                                                "device_id" : [
                                                                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                                                ],
                                                                "partner_id" : [
                                                                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                                                ],
                                                                "date_created" : [
                                                                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                                                ]
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        },
                                        "rejectedPlans" : [
                                                {
                                                        "stage" : "PROJECTION_SIMPLE",
                                                        "transformBy" : {
                                                                "date_created" : 1,
                                                                "device_id" : 1,
                                                                "global_campaign_id" : 1,
                                                                "partner_id" : 1,
                                                                "_id" : 0
                                                        },
                                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                                                "inputStage" : {
                                                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                                                "global_campaign_id" : 1
                                                                        },
                                                                        "indexName" : "global_campaign_id_1",
                                                                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                                                                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                                                "global_campaign_id" : [ ]
                                                                        },
                                                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                                                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                                                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                                                "global_campaign_id" : [
                                                                                        "[3151.0, 3151.0]",
                                                                                        "[3207.0, 3207.0]",
                                                                                        "[3208.0, 3208.0]",
                                                                                        "[3209.0, 3209.0]",
                                                                                        "[3210.0, 3210.0]"
                                                                                ]
                                                                        }
                                                                }
                                                        }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                        "stage" : "PROJECTION_SIMPLE",
                                                        "transformBy" : {
                                                                "date_created" : 1,
                                                                "device_id" : 1,
                                                                "global_campaign_id" : 1,
                                                                "partner_id" : 1,
                                                                "_id" : 0
                                                        },
                                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                                                "inputStage" : {
                                                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                                                "global_campaign_id" : 1,
                                                                                "date_created" : 1
                                                                        },
                                                                        "indexName" : "global_campaign_id_1_date_created_1",
                                                                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                                                                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                                                "global_campaign_id" : [ ],
                                                                                "date_created" : [ ]
                                                                        },
                                                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                                                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                                                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                                                "global_campaign_id" : [
                                                                                        "[3151.0, 3151.0]",
                                                                                        "[3207.0, 3207.0]",
                                                                                        "[3208.0, 3208.0]",
                                                                                        "[3209.0, 3209.0]",
                                                                                        "[3210.0, 3210.0]"
                                                                                ],
                                                                                "date_created" : [
                                                                                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                                                                ]
                                                                        }
                                                                }
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        ]
                                },
                                "executionStats" : {
                                        "executionSuccess" : true,
                                        "nReturned" : 304244,
                                        "executionTimeMillis" : 1363,
                                        "totalKeysExamined" : 304246,
                                        "totalDocsExamined" : 0,
                                        "executionStages" : {
                                                "stage" : "PROJECTION_COVERED",
                                                "nReturned" : 304244,
                                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 112,
                                                "works" : 304246,
                                                "advanced" : 304244,
                                                "needTime" : 1,
                                                "needYield" : 0,
                                                "saveState" : 322,
                                                "restoreState" : 322,
                                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                                "transformBy" : {
                                                        "date_created" : 1,
                                                        "device_id" : 1,
                                                        "global_campaign_id" : 1,
                                                        "partner_id" : 1,
                                                        "_id" : 0
                                                },
                                                "inputStage" : {
                                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                        "nReturned" : 304244,
                                                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 73,
                                                        "works" : 304246,
                                                        "advanced" : 304244,
                                                        "needTime" : 1,
                                                        "needYield" : 0,
                                                        "saveState" : 322,
                                                        "restoreState" : 322,
                                                        "isEOF" : 1,
                                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                                "global_campaign_id" : 1,
                                                                "device_id" : 1,
                                                                "partner_id" : 1,
                                                                "date_created" : 1
                                                        },
                                                        "indexName" : "global_campaign_id_1_device_id_1_partner_id_1_date_created_1",
                                                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                                                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                                "global_campaign_id" : [ ],
                                                                "device_id" : [ ],
                                                                "partner_id" : [ ],
                                                                "date_created" : [ ]
                                                        },
                                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                                "global_campaign_id" : [
                                                                        "[3151.0, 3151.0]",
                                                                        "[3207.0, 3207.0]",
                                                                        "[3208.0, 3208.0]",
                                                                        "[3209.0, 3209.0]",
                                                                        "[3210.0, 3210.0]"
                                                                ],
                                                                "device_id" : [
                                                                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                                                ],
                                                                "partner_id" : [
                                                                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                                                ],
                                                                "date_created" : [
                                                                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                                                ]
                                                        },
                                                        "keysExamined" : 304246,
                                                        "seeks" : 2,
                                                        "dupsTested" : 0,
                                                        "dupsDropped" : 0
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        },
                        "nReturned" : NumberLong(304244),
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberLong(803)
                },
                {
                        "$group" : {
                                "_id" : {
                                        "global_campaign_id" : "$global_campaign_id",
                                        "device_id" : "$device_id",
                                        "partner_id" : "$partner_id"
                                },
                                "date_last" : {
                                        "$max" : "$date_created"
                                },
                                "partner_id" : {
                                        "$first" : "$partner_id"
                                },
                                "campaign_id" : {
                                        "$first" : "$global_campaign_id"
                                },
                                "device_id" : {
                                        "$first" : "$device_id"
                                }
                        },
                        "nReturned" : NumberLong(84),
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberLong(1358)
                }
        ],
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "nosql-lurity",
                "port" : 27017,
                "version" : "4.4.13",
                "gitVersion" : "df25c71b8674a78e17468f48bcda5285decb9246"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: can you add output also from db.<collection>.explain("executionStats").aggregate([your query here])  , also answers to the question: 1) db.collection.stats().size , RAM size? , CPU num? , wiredTiger->cacheGBsize?

Comment: @R2D2 I added result of explain to the question. It seems to be ok. Winning plan uses index.

Comment: according to the executionStats your query return 300k docs in   1363 ms  ( 1,3 sec ) and the indexes seems to be used , what is the total size of your collection maybe documents are pretty big? is it still timeouting ? do you have enoguth RAM memory? also aggregations requiere CPU ...

Comment: Collection has 200 mil docs. I had 2 mil in the question. So its is really big. But docs are pretty small one level documents with about 10 items.

Comment: what about RAM? storage engine? cpu?

Comment: If it would be ram or cpu problem it would not send an error? I dont know.

Comment: Hmm if I run request in mongo shell it works and returns result documents. But if I do it in php it does not work.

Comment: maybe some connection timeout that you need to extend from php driver ...

Comment: Thank you for your time. I need to test it. It seems issue is on php side.